# How take modal as data type for field of another modal in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here I have Seller modal which contains the contact field. I created a new model name as Contact which has fields contact_number and address.

I can simply give a foreign key to the contact field of Seller model to Contact model.

But here I want to use the Contact model as a new data type for the contact field of Seller model.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=False, null=False)
    address = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name


class Seller(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
    company_profile = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    contact = Contact() #Here I want use Contact model as data type for the contact field

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.company_name
```

Is this possible?

If yes Can anyone please Guide me for that. I am New in Django, I only have basic knowledge of Django.

Here I am using PostgreSQL as a database.

Comment: You should use foreign key. Custom fields are possible too, see this link for details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields/

Answer (score -1):

what ever database your are using django will take care of that, follow the documentation for changes in settings if your are using different database instead of sqllite.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
 contact_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=False, null=False)
 address = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)

 def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % self.name


class Seller(models.Model):
  company_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
  company_profile = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
  contact = models.Foreignkey(Contact,on_delete=models.CASCADE)      
  def __str__(self):
     return "%s" % self.company_name
```

once go through documentation of foreignkey and models for more info @https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/